# How can I Create custom analytics with the data that I store in Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform, analytics

I cannot find sample code for creating Custom Analytics for my Parse.com application . Is it possible to use Google Analytics instead ?

Comment: Documentation exists for custom analytics with Parse, across all their API's. For example, https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#analytics-custom/iOS

Answer (score 0):

check this example.

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.parse.com/1/events/Buy")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("<APPLICATION-KEY>", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
request.setValue("<REST-KEY>", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")

 var parameter: NSDictionary = ["dimensions" :["product" : ["name" : "macpro", "price" : "350"]]]
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameter, options: nil, error: nil)

Alamofire.request(request).response { (request, response, result, error) -> Void in
     // handle response
     println("\(request) \t \(response) \t \(result) \t \(error) ")
}
```

This example uses [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).